# How to reset the resolv.conf file on a Synology Diskstation NAS?

Tags: domain-name-system, network-attached-storage, synology

Quick question from a newbie: Is there a way to simply reset the resolv.conf file? According to Synology support, my resolv.conf shows some strange DNS servers, which I have never specified. How can I reset the file so it simply uses the DNS servers from my default gateway (i.e. my router)? I have specified my DNS servers there and want my DS to use these DNS servers.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to enable ssh service on Synology NAS, login and edit `/etc/resolv.conf`
Here is a [page](https://kb.synology.com/en-global/DSM/tutorial/How_to_login_to_DSM_with_root_permission_via_SSH_Telnet) which describe how to enable it.

> Enable SSH service
>
> Go to the terminal setting page on your Synology device:
> Synology NAS: DSM Control Panel > Terminal & SNMP > Terminal
> Synology Router: SRM Control Panel > Services > System Services > Terminal
> Tick Enable SSH service.
> Specify a port number for SSH connections and save the settings. To ensure system security, we suggest replacing the default port 22 with another one

Comment: Thank you. And once I am connected, it would work just like a normal text editor? I.e. I can open the resoilv.conf file and edit it in Notepad?

Comment: @bakgwei, AFAIK this NAS is Linux based, so you should learn how to use text editor(s) in Linux.

Comment: OK, will do. Thanks for your help!